# Is there a "wildcard method" in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods

I am looking for a way to use a method of a class which is not defined in that class, but handled dynamically. What I would like to achieve, to take an example, is to move from

```
class Hello:
    def aaa(self, msg=""):
        print("{msg} aaa".format(msg=msg))

    def bbb(self, msg=""):
        print("{msg} bbb".format(msg=msg))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    h = Hello()
    h.aaa("hello")
    h.bbb("hello")

# hello aaa
# hello bbb
```

to the possibility of using `aaa` and `bbb` (and others) within the class without the need to define them explicitly. For the example above that would be a construction which receives the name of the method used (`aaa` for instance) and format a message accordingly.

In other other words, a "wildcard method" which would itself handle its name and perform conditional actions depending on the name. In pseudocode (to replicate the example above)

```
def *wildcard*(self, msg=""):
    method = __name__which__was__used__to__call__me__
    print("{msg} {method}".format(msg=msg, method=method))
```

Is such a construction possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could overload the class' [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) method:

```
class Hello:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def f(msg=""):
            print("{} {}".format(msg, name))
        return f

if __name__ == "__main__":
    h = Hello()
    h.aaa("hello")
    h.bbb("hello")
```

Result:

```
hello aaa
hello bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the names of the methods in advance, you could do this with a decorator that adds all the methods for you.

```
from functools import partial

def glue(f, names=[]):
    def wrapper(cls):
        method = getattr(cls,f)
        for name in names:
            setattr(cls, name, partial(method,name=name))
        return cls
    return wrapper
```

Use it like this:

```
@glue(f = 'wildcard', names = ['aaa', 'bbb'])
class Hello():
    def wildcard(self, msg='', name=''):
        print("{} {}".format(msg, name))
```

If you are unfamiliar with decorators, the`@` syntax above is equivalent to doing this after the class definition:

```
Hello = glue(f = 'wildcard', names = ['aaa', 'bbb'])(Hello)
```

Answer (score -2):

I found above answers a bit hard to comprehend so I do this.

Inspired by Django's code.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        for arg in ('aaa', 'bbb'):
            # generate a new function based on the template function.
            setattr(self, f'make_{arg}', partialmethod(self._make_ARG, arg=arg))

    def _make_ARG(self, arg, **kwargs):
        value = getattr(self, arg)
        # override make_{ARG} function to generate an argument based on codex.
        return value
```

Comment: This assumes `aaa` and `bbb` are known (which is not the case, it should handle any method name)